# get WordPress variable from external php file does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two variables in an external file

*function.php*

```
$bottomID   =  get_post_meta($post->ID, "bottom", true);

$xstring    =  "This is a string";
```

now if I echo them from my *index.php*

```
echo $bottomID;
echo $xstring;
```

I only get the value from `$xstring` but not from `$bottomID`

I know that `$bottomID` works since if I have it in the `index.php` file it echo out a value.

Cant figure out whats the problem

Any ideas?

Comment: does it shows any error ?

Comment: not a single one i I have active the error messages.

Comment: if xstring works then bottomid also should work? give us more details?

Comment: @ferozakbar yes it should work:) But hey I think i need to actually include the wordpress configuration file to my external page.

Will try that and give you an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a variable in `function.php` it is in the global scope, variable will be visible in `index.php` only because they are loaded in the same scope, but it is not available to all of your templates. Most templates are loaded by a function, and in PHP any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope, so you must explicit define a variable as [global](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

In your case, variable is set and the value is `false` ( test with: `var_dump( isset( $bottomID ) );` in `index.php` ), that's because you use a `global $post`, that not yet exists, as parameter in the `get_post_meta()` function, so the return value of that function is `false`.

Comment: thank you @Danijel. That was very helpfull information!

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function in `functions.php` and call it in `index.php`.

```
function get_id_xstring()
{
    global $post;
    $return = array(
        'id'      => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bottom', true ),
        'xstring' => 'This is a string';
    );
    return $return;
}
```

And in `index.php`:

```
$my_vars = get_id_xstring();
echo $my_vars['id']; // bottomID
echo $my_vars['xstring'];
```